# VMPlayer mounting share on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, mount, permissions, vmware, windows-10

I have enabled share on my VM and it works fine(so that is not a issue). Now I am trying to mount it to my user directory. I am going by [VM Player 12 documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/player-12-linux/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.player.linux.using.doc%2FGUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html)
`mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /home/user1/shares`  **Mounts all shares** to /home/user1/shares
I have my folder ~/Downloads/share, but when I issue command I get error:

```
me@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ ~/Downloads/share
```

**Error: cannot mount filesystem: No such device**   - Is this some kind of file permission issue?

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 Apr 16 09:04 share
```

I can copy files from /mnt/hgfs/shares onto ~/Downloads/share

Note: Using 16.04 (not 14.04) but somehow I do not get that tag